# How to reference a Property in a Generic Object using a For Loop in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, object, generics

I am trying to create a generic method for sorting a List of objects based on whatever property value was given.  e.g. For a customer list I may want to sort by the customer name which is a `string` value or the customer ID which is an `int` value.

For the purposes of this question I will use a `Customer` class that contains two properties `Name`, `Id` and a method `CollectionData()` that returns a hard coded collection of `Customer`s.

The method should return a sorted collection of `List<Customer>`.

The method receives two parameters `List<Customer>` and `nameof(Customer.Name)` or `nameof(Customer.Id)`

Currently I am calling the method as below but am open to suggestions for improvements:

```
SortObjectList(Customer.CollectionData(), nameof(Customer.Name));
```

Here is my `SortObjectList` method

```
public static List<TObjectType> SortObjectList<TObjectType, TNameOfProperty>(List<TObjectType> objectList, TNameOfProperty propertyName)
{
   // Code for sorting algorithm here
}
```

Because my method is generic I am unsure of how use `propertyName` in a loop.

For example.

```
public static List<TObjectType> SortObjectList<TObjectType, TNameOfProperty>(List<TObjectType> objectList, TNameOfProperty propertyName)
{

   int listCount = objectList.Count;
     
   for (int i = 0; i < listCount; i++)
   {

       // Get the current object
       TObjectType currentObject = objectList[i];

       /* 
        Here I would like to access the propertyName value
        e.g. currentObject.propertyName  (I am aware this will not work but using this to portray my concept)
        */
   }


}
```

How am I able to reference a property name for an object?

**NOTE:** I need to use an index to reference and iterate over the collection and therefore am unable to use a foreach loop as per previous questions/answers posted on Stackoverflow.

I need to compare the current `propertyName` value `[i]` and the current `propertyName` value +1 `[i + 1]`

e.g. For comparing an integer value I would like to use something like

```
// Compare Integer Value
if(currentObject[i].propertyName == currentObject[i+1].propertyName)
{
   // Code if statement true
}

// Compare String Value
if (currentObject[i].propertyName.CompareTo(currentObject[i+1].propertyName) > 0)
{
    // Code if statement true
}
```

I hope this all makes sense? Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use LINQ OrderBy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0

```cs
var enumerableOrderedByName = Customers.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
var enumerableOrderedById = Customers.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I only started learning C# recently and haven't got around to learning LINQ yet so this might seem like a silly question but can I use an indexer with LINQ?

Comment: The main thing to remember about LINQ is that it is lazy evaluated meaning that it will only evaluate when you enumerate the enumerable, which is very good for keeping memory consumption low, but everything isn't available in memory, so you can't index to a location. If you want to be able to use an indexer you can use the LINQ methods `ToList()` or `ToArray()` which will force things to be evaluated and stored into memory as an array or list.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  I will keep this question open for a little bit and if no further answers I will mark yours as the accepted answer.